# Redirect within an int class if error without changing class type

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I am new to c# and am having an issue with trying to set up a catch on a specific class.

I have plenty of trycatch and redirects in my code already but 1 part I cannot seem to get is the below, I know the issue is because the class is an int and should be an ActionResult to use a redirect, but then I am getting an error on the  return int. I need the class to work for both.

Current class in my BaseController that works and I call GetUID() on most other controllers;

```
    public int GetUID()
    {
        return int.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UID"].ToString());
    }
```

The issue I have is if someone's session times out, they will get an error but I want them to be redirected to the login page.

So I tried to do the below;

```
    public int GetUID()
    {
        try
        {
            return int.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UID"].ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

because the class is an int class I get an error on the redirect: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'int'".

I have also tried to do the below;

```
    public ActionResult GetUID()
    {
        try
        {
            return int.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UID"].ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

But then I get the opposite error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult'".

Is there a way that I can keep the class to return an int BUT if there is an error to redirect to the login page?
I have looked on SO and Google and I can see plenty of queries about converting from View to Action, etc. but nothing similar to this.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define and return an `int` error code that describe redirect action and when you see it you've to call `RedirectToAction` method.

**EDIT:**
You can't return different types. Then or you return an object:

```
public object GetUID(){...}
```

and in your BaseController you can do:

```
object o = GetUID();
if (o is int UID)
    //do your stuff 
else if (o is ActionResult action)
    //execute the action
```

the alternative is to define error codes, for example negative numbers are errors. Then you'll have:

```
public const int ReturnHomeError = -1;
public int GetUID()
{
    try
    {
        return int.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UID"].ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return ReturnHomeError;
    }
}
```

and in your BaseController you can do:

```
int uid = GetUID();
switch(uid)
{
    case ReturnHomeError:
        //Call RedirectToAction("Login", "Account")
        break;
    default:
        //Do your stuff
        break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, as I said I'm new to c# so I'm not sure what that means, could you give me an example or direct me to a web page that describes that in more detail? I am not sure what wording to use when I'm googling my problem, thanks

Comment: edit version is more than enough to set me on my way, thanks.